# Trying to save my CNN model in a Pickle file but getting a TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects

Tags: python, service, deployment, pickle, faster-rcnn

Tried `2 methods` both are giving same errors please help me getting it saved as pickle file so that I can use the model at a later date.

I am looking to create `service.exe` with the model please suggest a best approach as I am fresher to data science

```
result = classifier.predict(kyc_test_image)
kyc_training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'pan'
else:
    prediction = 'driv'

kyc_model = classifier

import pickle
modelname = 'cnn_kyc'
outfile = open(modelname,'wb')
pickle.dump(kyc_model,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-865fb4ce2e0b> in <module>
----> 1 pickle.dump(kyc_model,outfile)
      2 outfile.close()

TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

**2nd method**

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.dump(kyc_model, 'cnn_kyc.pkl')

cnn_from_joblib = joblib.load('cnn_kyc.pkl') 

cnn_from_joblib.predict(kyc_test_image)
```

Comment: Formatted answer to make more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
import joblib        # to save models

# For Saving
python
path_name = "../../../"    # some path


model_name = 'model_name.sav' # I think saving it to sav format maybe will help y


joblib.dump(model, path_name + model_name)

# For Loading
joblib.load(path_name + model_name)
```